# How to use accumulators to add tables together?

Tags: kdb

I have a function `func` which returns a table given a single parameter of the symbol e.g. `AAPL.

I would like to add each table together (they have the same keyed column with same number of rows) however the over accumulator doesn't work as expected.

I have tried `` (+/)func[`AAPL `MSFT `TSLA] `` which returns an error `'MSFT`. Also `` func`AAPL + func`MSFT + func`TSLA `` returns a `type` error, however if I assign each to a variable then add them, i.e. `` A:func`AAPL `` `` B:func`MSFT `` `` C:func`TSLA `` then do `A+B+C` then it works.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By add together, do you mean join?

```
q)func:{n:10;([]sym:n#x;price:n?100f;qty:n?100i)}

q)(uj/) func each `APPL`GOOG
sym  price    qty
-----------------
APPL 15.08133 2  
APPL 15.67317 39 
APPL 97.85    64 
APPL 70.43314 49 
APPL 94.41671 82 
APPL 78.33686 40 
APPL 40.99561 88 
APPL 61.08817 77 
APPL 49.76492 30 
APPL 40.87545 17 
GOOG 16.27662 20 
GOOG 68.84756 30 
GOOG 81.77547 34 
GOOG 75.20102 77 
GOOG 10.86824 61 
GOOG 95.98964 70 
GOOG 3.668341 36 
GOOG 64.30982 12 
GOOG 67.08738 97 
GOOG 67.89082 92
```

Answer (score 2):

This expression is failing due to missing brackets.

```
func`AAPL + func`MSFT + func`TSLA
```

As q works from right to left you are adding a symbol to the output of `func`, essentially:

```
`MSFT + func`TSLA
```

Which gives a `'type` error.

You can fix with brackets.

```
func[`AAPL] + func[`MSFT] + func[`TSLA]
```

An easier way to add the tables is with `pj`, especially if using a list of symbols. The arguments can be passed to `func` with `each`.

```
(pj/) func each `APPL`GOOG
```

If the intention is to join rather than add then use `uj` instead.

This is similar to your first expression which can be fixed with `each` or `'`.

```
(+/)func'[`AAPL`MSFT`TSLA]
```